# Why am I printing Â» instead of »?

Tags: html, css, unicode, character-encoding

I want to just show this: `»`, but `Â»` is showing instead. Why is `Â` being added to it? How come it's not just the double right arrow? What's wrong with my code?

CSS

```
#buttonServices1{
  transition: all 0.5s;
}


#buttonServices1 span {
  transition:0.5s;
}

#buttonServices1 span:after {
  content: '»';
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#buttonServices1:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

#buttonServices1:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button id="buttonServices1"><span>Services</span></button>
```

Picture:

[image: SEE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is `Â` being added to it?

Because your stylesheet is saved as UTF-8, but the browser is decoding it using Windows-1252. This is probably because the page that's referencing the stylesheet has no declared encoding and the browser is arbitrarily guessing the Windows-1252, which is typically the default encoding on Western European locales. The byte sequence `0xC2 0xBB` represents `»` in UTF-8 but `Â»` in Windows-1252.

Adding the `<meta charset>` declaration in Akjm's answer to the page(s) that reference the stylesheet should make this work. If you can't do this (for example because you are making a stylesheet that might be referenced by other people's pages which could be in any encoding), alternatives are:

1. encoding the character using CSS backslash-escapes, as in @RobFonseca's answer. (The HTML character reference syntax in @Akjm's answer is not effective here.)
2. putting the rule `@charset "utf-8";` at the top of the stylesheet to tell the browser that the stylesheet has its own encoding, independently of whatever the page uses
3. setting the web server to serve the stylesheet with an HTTP `Content-Type: text/css;charset=utf-8` header

Support for approaches 2–4 has traditionally been rocky, though I haven't checked browser support recently.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a rendering error with the character rendering.

First thing's first, make sure that in your head tags you have something like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Then, try replacing the character in the content attribute with the charcode

```
content: '&raquo;'
/* OR USE THIS */
content: '&#187;'
```

Comment: html entities like ``&raquo;`` or ``&#187;`` do not work in css

Answer (score 1):

The CSS content property requires you to use Unicode hex escapes

```
content: '\00bb',
```

Here is a useful chart of them
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/glyphs/

Comment: this does not answer the question (nice workaround though)