# Does anyone else have this issue with vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a `.txt` file that has the pound symbol in `£`. When I use `filename.read()` it will print the pound sign how it should be, but it will also print with another letter that I didn't add which is `Â`

Anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Very likely related: [Why am I printing Â» instead of »?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37847771/11082165). Different technology, same encoding issue. Make sure the text file, Python, and VS code's terminal are all using the same encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file encoding is UTF-8, but read as (probably) Windows-1252.

The reason for two characters is UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding, and the pound sign is encoded as `C2 A3`, but Windows-1252 is a single byte encoding and the pound sign is only encoded as `A3`.  `C2` in Windows-1252 is `Â`.

Example:

```py
>>> with open('test.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
...   f.write('£')
...
1
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:  # default encoding...on windows usually Windows-1252
...   print(f.read())
...
Â£
```

Open the file with UTF-8 encoding instead:

```py
>>> with open('test.txt',encoding='utf8') as f:
...   print(f.read())
...
£
```

If the symbol is in source code, make sure Visual Studio Code is configured to open source in UTF-8.